# PHP: Manipulating data a user inputs into a browser

Tags: php, input

I would like for a user to be able to input data in a text field on my website. WITH this data I would like for them to be able manipulate it.

For example:

Let's say someone needs all the letters in a paragraph capitalized and on my website I have a PHP script that does just that. How do I create a means for them to use my script?

Like so:

- paste paragraph into left text field
- press 'action button' or in this example 'capitalize letters' button
- text in left text field gets ran through the script and becomes all capitalized
- text now appears in right text field

A better way to ask this I guess is how do I connect the users input with the script and display the output once it's been ran?

Comment: What you need is some Javascript and AJAX to communicate with the server. Please do a little research on these. Alternatively, you can use a plain old form submission which reloads the page to do the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely lost their. I know about using the regular submission forms just not how to connect them. NI can build a submission form. Not sure past that tho.

Comment: Then you may need some more training in the basics of the art. What's your problem doing this using a regular form submission? Have you any Javascript experience?

Comment: Neg, no javascript experience, although if javascript is what I need it's not something I can't learn with enough youtube tutorials. I'm sure this is semi basic stuff.

Comment: also with the submission form I ONLY know how to make the form not how to do stuff with the data they enter.

Comment: Then, seriously, read some more tutorials or manuals or books, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your fields in a form in the HTML file, for example like this:

```
<form method="post" action="script_that_does_the_action.php">
    Left paragraph: <input type="text" id="leftP" name="leftP"><br>
    Right paragraph: <input type="text" id="rightP" name="rightP">
</form>
```

and then in your script that does all of the action, you can fetch the user input like this:

```
$userInput = $_POST['leftP'];
//do the capitalization now here
//store the result somehow. Maybe using sessions like this: $_SESSION["result"];
//then you have to redirect the page back to where the text fields are for example using header("location: ");
```

and now that you are back in the index page (if I may call it like that), paste the resulting value to the right field:

```
<input type="text" id="rightP" name="rightP" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["result"]; ?>">
```

Be sure that both of your files (the action script and index file) are in .php format, and that you start the session with session_start();

That's only one example...the most basic one. If you want to make it in the proper way, I'd also suggest using javascript :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I am going to edit my question and add something. Should only take me a second.